# visual studio grid snap to edge spacing

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2008, compact-framework

I'm designing a form in VS2008 and I want to snap controls to the left and right edges of the form but with more space than it gets now.

I tried changing the gridsize but that doesn't do it.

The form is for the compact framework so i'm designing for a smartphone I don't know if that makes a difference. I guess it ought to be the same setting.

Is there a setting somewhere that holds the space between the control and form edge?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The form's Padding property has a somewhat mysterious effect on the snap location.  Setting Padding.Left to 1 makes it snap to X=4, 2 to 5 etc.  No idea how well that reproduces but might be good enough for what you're trying to do.  Directly editing the Location.X property would certainly work too.